# Excel VBA application.match returns error 13 (type mismatch) on a .csv file

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have the following Excel VBA code:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim SearchRequest As Workbook
Dim SecondCols As Variant
Dim businessNameStartRow As Variant

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set SearchRequest = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("test.csv")
SecondCols = SearchRequest.Worksheets(1).Range("B1").EntireColumn
businessNameStartRow = Application.Match("business_name", SecondCols, 0)
```

When I run it, Application.match returned error 13 (type mismatch), but when I saved the .csv file as an .xls file and run the same code against the .xls file, it was fine.

Hope somebody can explain why and give a solution without changing the file.

Comment: This is a wooly hunch but I've had a poor experience using application.match with variables - the match would work fine as an Excel formula but not in VB. As a test try putting "business_name" in a cell and using that cell as the first argument. To get round it in the past I've just used a for-loop to test for the value on the column in question, the performance difference is negligible.

Comment: Most likely, the string `"business_name"` is not found exactly like that in column 2.  If that is the case, and you use `Worksheetfunction.Match` instead, you should see 1004 error.